# What is wrong with my proof: $-1 = 1$?

Tags: complex-numbers, fake-proofs

I have some theories about why this could by wrong but I still haven't something that convinces me. What is wrong with this proof:

$ -1 = i^2 = i.i = \sqrt{-1}.\sqrt{-1} = \sqrt{(-1).(-1)}= \sqrt1 = 1 $

This would imply that:
$1 = -1$

Which is obviously false.

So my theory is that it's not a great idea to write $i = \sqrt{-1}$, but I'm not sure why...

Comment: Because $(-i)^2=-1$ too.

Comment: I'm fairly sure this has been on this site before.  At any rate, the rule that generally fails here is
$$
\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt a \sqrt b
$$
This is true when $a,b \geq 0$, but not in our generalization to the complex numbers.

Comment: $x^a x^a \neq x^{a + a}$ if $x < 0$.

Comment: How are people still answering this question?

Comment: @GitGud how are people still asking it? I found 4 duplicates and didn't know which one to flag it as.

Comment: You seem to forget that $\sqrt{1}=\pm1$ (and not just $1$).

Comment: How are people still upvoting the answers?

Comment: @barakmanos: usually the square root is defined to be a function and the positive branch is preferred. Hence $\sqrt1=1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The flaw is in assuming that the rule $\sqrt x\sqrt y=\sqrt{xy}$ holds with imaginary numbers. You just show us a counter-example.

Comment: Crossed with @Peter.

Answer (score 6):

The step $\sqrt{-1}\times \sqrt{-1}=\sqrt{(-1)\times(-1)}$ is incorrect. Such a law is only valid for nonnegative arguments.