# Strange problem with the imaginary unit

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, fake-proofs, paradoxes

In class while messing with fractions and complex numbers I found this "paradox"
$$
\sqrt{-1}=\sqrt{-1}
$$
$$
\sqrt{\frac{-1}{1}}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{-1}}
$$
$$
\frac{\sqrt{-1}}{\sqrt{1}}=\frac{\sqrt{1}}{\sqrt{-1}}
$$
$$
\sqrt{-1}\cdot \sqrt{-1}=\sqrt{1}\cdot \sqrt{1}
$$
$$
i\cdot i=\sqrt1
$$
$$
-1=1
$$
Could anybody explain me what is wrong with this passages?

Comment: This might be related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1122038/what-is-wrong-with-my-proof-1-1?rq=1

Comment: notice that not only i^2 = $\sqrt{-1}$ , (-i)^2 =$\sqrt{-1}$ too

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root Go down to "Notes". It explains why step 4 in your "proof" is incorrect.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Powers_of_complex_numbers) states "The powers of negative real numbers are not always defined and are discontinuous even where defined. In fact, they are only defined when the exponent is a rational number with the denominator being an odd integer. When dealing with complex numbers the complex number operation is normally used instead."

Answer (score 3):

$\sqrt{ab}\neq \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ iff a or b <$0$

Comment: Ok but why is that?

Comment: By definition. And the definition is constructed so as to avoid exactly the contradiction that you bring up in your question.